# ./asinstall not found in while docker build using dockerfile?

Tags: node.js, dockerfile, aerospike

I am trying to build docker image using docker file . The docker file will contain aerospike database creation.

```
RUN wget -O aerospike.tgz 'https://www.aerospike.com/download/server/latest/artifact/ubuntu18'
RUN tar -xvf aerospike.tgz
RUN cd aerospike-server-community-*-ubuntu18*
RUN ./asinstall
```

Comment: That can't be the entire dockerfile; it's missing e.g. a `FROM` statement. Please post the full file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y curl python2.7 python
RUN TEMPDIR=$(mktemp -d) && \
    cd $TEMPDIR && \
    curl -L 'https://www.aerospike.com/download/server/latest/artifact/ubuntu18' | tar xzv --strip-components 1 && \
    ./asinstall && \
    cd / && \
    rm -rf $TEMPDIR
```

seems to work.

Comment: Thanks its works fine. but aerospike service is not running when I am log into that container ?                                                                                              WARN Failed to connect to seed 127.0.0.1 3000. AEROSPIKE_ERR_CONNECTION Socket write error: 111, 127.0.0.1:3000
Error -10: Failed to connect